# The enemy's healthbar decreases in its entirety with a single collision

Tags: ios, swift4

he problem is that when the player collides with the enemy the health of the enemy in healthBar does not decrease the indicated amount. it simply decreases in its entirety 
I can not find a way to update the enemy's healthbar in the func update and try the func didBegin (_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)

```
enter code here
```

func initZombie(){

```
      let enemy = Enemigo(imageNamed: "zombie1")

        var textures:[SKTexture] = []
        for i in 1...2 {
            textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "zombie\(i)"))

        }
        let anima:SKAction = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 15.0)
        enemy.run(SKAction.group([
            SKAction.repeatForever(anima),
            SKAction.speed(to: 60.0, duration: 0)


            ]),withKey: "animation")





    enemy.healt = 300
    enemy.exp = 100


    enemy.barraEnemy = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.green, size: enemy.barravidaSizeE)
    enemy.barraEnemyBack = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: enemy.barravidaSizeE.width + 300, height:  enemy.barravidaSizeE.height + 30))



   enemy.barraEnemy.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x , y: enemy.position.y - 150)
    enemy.barraEnemy.zPosition = 101
   enemy.barraEnemy.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0 , y: 0.5)
    enemy.addChild(enemy.barraEnemy)

    enemy.barraEnemyBack.position = CGPoint(x: enemy.position.x , y: enemy.position.y - 150)
    enemy.barraEnemyBack.zPosition = 100
    enemy.barraEnemyBack.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    enemy.addChild(enemy.barraEnemyBack)

    enemy.barraEnemy.size = CGSize(width: enemy.barravidaSizeE.width + CGFloat(enemy.healt) , height: enemy.barravidaSizeE.height + 30)

    enemy.zPosition = 100
        //enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x:random(min: -1100 , max: 1100), y: random(min: -400 , max: 400))
    enemy.name = "zombie"
    enemy.setScale(0.4)




        addChild(enemy)



        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
        enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 3
        enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true




}






    enter 
   code 
   here
```

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

```
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA

    }
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 2 {
        life += 100

        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()

    }
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == 3  {
            score += 1

            if let myEnemy = secondBody.node as? Enemigo {

                myEnemy.healt -= playerAtack

                life -= zombieAtack

                myEnemy.barraEnemy.size = CGSize(width: myEnemy.barravidaSizeE.width + CGFloat(myEnemy.healt), height: myEnemy.barravidaSizeE.height)



                print(myEnemy.healt)
                if myEnemy.healt <= 0 {
                    playerAtack += 10
                    life += 100
                    spawnItem(point: secondBody.node!.position)
                    secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()



                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: when colliding the player with the enemy instead of decreasing by 10 points the health in the size of healthbar decreases in its entirety @Hima